# Angular 7 application having issue with ngx-device-detector.js

Tags: angular

I am trying to run the application with following version

[image]

Giving the following exception in console when I try to run the application and the application stopped in the busyindicator page only
[image]

I tried everything uninstalling and reinstalling the node_Modules. Deleting Package-lock.json and install the npm install  still not working.

My machine used to have angular 10 version I downgraded it also but still not working

Comment: Which version of ngx-device-detector is installed?

Comment: "ngx-device-detector": "^1.4.6" this is existing in package.json file

Comment: Hi @NAGASREE were you able to fix this

Answer (score -1):

Try to use or install the following package

```
npm i ngx-device-detector@1.3.3
```

It might help you out regardless of getting errors on inspect element on console,

A minor issue is that it will support angular 7+ versions but it might not show you device name which you might be searching for on JSON object.